# 'The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared' issues

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, meta-tags

I made a form that users can fill out and it checks if the user correctly inserts the email.

- If it returns false: the user gets to see an error message.
- If it returns true: it will show the user a confirmation message but it will also `INSERT` the data into the database.

So the problem occurred when I tried to add the form in the PHP file so I could make an alert or give the user the error message on the same page. I started to get this error:

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

So I tried to restore this by reverting to the older version, I had to cut and paste a few pieces of code but nothing too complicated. For some strange reason I still get this error. Naturally I checked the similar topics on this issue here on Stackoverflow but none of the answers got me any further. For example adding the `meta` information in the header of the page,I also created a PHP header like this: `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`After that I read some articles about this error but none helped me resolve this issue.

Here is an example of my code. It is this page I get the error on:

```
 <?php    
include_once('credentials.php');
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());
include_once('functions.php');

 $apples = sanitize($_POST['Apple']);
 $oranges = sanitize($_POST['Orange']);
 $melons = sanitize($_POST['Melon']);
 $pears = sanitize($_POST['Pear']);
 $strawberries = sanitize($_POST['Strawberry']);
 $grapes = sanitize($_POST['Grape']);               
    if($_POST['Grape'] == 'Yes')
    { $grapes = 1; }
    else
    { $grapes = 0; } 
$blueberries = sanitize($_POST['Blueberry']);

if (checkStrawberries($strawberries) == true) {    
    mysql_query("   INSERT INTO tablename (Name, Weight, Color, Ripeness, Age, Origin, Destination) 
            VALUES ('$apples', '$oranges', '$melons', '$Pears', '$strawberries', '$grapes', '$blueberries') ");

    or die(mysql_error()); 

    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>   
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
                </head>
                <title>Page</title>
                <body>
                    True
                    <a href="../index.php">home</a>
                </body>
            </html>';
} else {
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>   
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
                </head>
                <title>Pagina</title>
                <body>
                    False
                    <a href="../index.php">home</a>
                </body>
            </html>';
}
?>
```

I had to rename the variables and classes as they have strong relations with the company I work for.

**EDIT**: This error is being produced by the console log in Firefox using Firebug.

**EDIT 2**: Changed the var and function names to avoid confusion and to illustrate the exchange of data within this application.

**EDIT 3**: I tried to figure out what exactly in my code is producing this error, because I tested the encoding part with the test case presented to me below by Dobromir Velev and that worked just fine. I decided to comment out the IF ELSE statement and I didnt get an error. So this seems to corrupt the page.

**I removed the echo's for now as it didn't add any value to this particular challenge.**

```
if (checkStrawberries($strawberries) == true) {    
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (Name, Weight, Color, Ripeness, Age, Origin, Destination) 
    VALUES ('$apples', '$oranges', '$melons', '$Pears', '$strawberries', '$grapes', '$blueberries') ");
    or die(mysql_error());
} else {
    echo 'FALSE';
}
```

The function checkStrawberries is this:

```
function checkEmail($email) {
if (!preg_match("/^( [a-zA-Z0-9] )+( [a-zA-Z0-9\._-] )*@( [a-zA-Z0-9_-] )+( [a-zA-Z0-9\._-] +)+$/" , $email)) {
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

The function sanitize is this:

```
function sanitize($dirty){
$clean = htmlspecialchars($dirty);
$cleaner = mysql_real_escape_string($clean);
return $cleaner;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see that message, what is producing it?

Comment: I hope you did not really name you function `function` ? (`function($_POST['1']);`). That will probably mess up some code as well since `function` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @jelmer I already stated that I had to change a few things regarding the names of vars and functions. This is due to a Non-Disclosure Agreement.

Comment: @MarioS Sorry I missed that. At least give them a descriptive name that represents the function. So we can guess how the data gets changed, maybe it will help us answer your question.

Comment: So, are you correctly setting a charset header? Can you see it in the response headers in the Firebug network tab?

Comment: `foo` is better than `function`, as `foo` is not a reserved keyword. No NDA requires you to write broken code as a testcase. :)

Comment: @deceze It seems that my information is getting passed along correctly, it shows the right content in the right places. However I am seeing a 500 Internal Server Error. The connection seems to work fine on other pages though(which are hosted on the same machine).

Comment: Some questions: Q1) Which output encoding are you using? Q2) Which binary sequence in your output is causing the error message in firefox (the exact number of invalid sequences, their byte-offsets and their byte-sequences). Q3) Where do these invalid byte-sequences come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion on the PHP chat, it seems the problem comes from the extra semicolon

From :

```
mysql_query(); or die();
```

To :

```
mysql_query() or die();
```

Comment: Thank you Touki! This was indeed the issue. Such a dumb error to overlook.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by trying a file with both the HTTP headers and the meta tags.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
</head>
<body>
text
</body>
</html>
```

If this doesn't trigger the error it is probably something in your code. For example the space before the `<?php` tag will prevent PHP from setting the HTTP header. Also if any content is returned by the include files file1.php or file2.php it might cause the browser to detect the encoding incorrectly

Comment: I don't think data is getting passed through the includes, they only contain a few functions.

Comment: Check the HTTP response headers - sometimes the HTTP server might modify the encoding

Comment: I tested this and it didn't produce any complications (as I expected) However I did identify the piece of code that is producing the errors. A more detailed explanation in the orignal post. +1 by the way :)